# Catch error in HTTP request to load NetworkImage: NetworkImageLoadException (HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, imageUrl)

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, crash

I have to show a CircleAvatar with a dynamic image (imageUrl) inside a NetworkImage widget.

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: const NetworkImage(imageUrl),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  radius: radius.r,
);
```

That image comes from an API and can have a broken link. If so, this causes the program to crash and throws the following error:

`NetworkImageLoadException (HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://www.linkofimg/img.png)`

It is expected to handle this NetworkImageLoadException in order to show an alternative/placeholder image when the original URL link is broken or not working for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled the network image issue related to 404 by using an errorBuilder.

```
Image.network(
       'Your image url...',
        errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace ){ 
     return Text('Your error widget...');
  }, 
),
```